# How can I typecheck recursively nested object literals?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

In TypeScript, you can use a function to evaluate the type of an object literal.

In this example, `createTestElement` takes in an object.
It does nothing to this object, but should throw an error if there is a type mismatch with `TestElement`. It uses the `TagNameT` generic type variable to make the `attributes` property accept keys depending on what `tagName` is given.

For instance, with `tagName: 'input'`, `type` can be set in the `attributes` but `href` will throw an error.

However, this approach fails for recursively nested object literals. In this example, `children` is an array of `TestElement`, but every `attributes` property in `children` has the same type, completely independent of what you set `tagName` to.

Specifically, the `attributes` property within `children` is the intersection type of every key in `ElementTypes`. That leaves only `className`, disallowing `href` and `type` in all instances.

```js
interface ElementTypes {
  a: {
    href?: string;
    className?: string;
  };

  input: {
    type?: string;
    className?: string;
  };
}

type TestElement<TagNameT extends keyof ElementTypes = keyof ElementTypes> = {
  tagName: TagNameT;
  attributes: { [attr in keyof ElementTypes[TagNameT]]: any };
  children?: TestElement[];
};

function createTestElement<TagNameT extends keyof ElementTypes>(
  testElement: TestElement<TagNameT>,
): TestElement<TagNameT> {
  return testElement;
}

createTestElement({
  tagName: "a",
  attributes: { href: "http://example.com" }, // ok
  children: [
    {
      tagName: "a",
      attributes: { href: "http://example.com" }, // error: Type '{ href: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ className?: any; }'.
    },
  ],
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIBsIFsLgCoCeADhAM7IDeAUMsnAFyU23IAWUEMA-I6WFKADmAbma0E6OKVIA5ODh7I+AkCOYBfADRVmoIgFcwjai2RhiERcqGjTEqbPmXe-Gxqrqd5ksjxkwGNi4YAA8eHCCcjh4yBAAHpAgACbkANYQBAD2MGiYOPgW5AC8yOlZOYH5YIQkpAB8yCUmZhFREIzhkU542uKswOhJHCCKfnyVwQDaALq9dGCuAEaGZIyUyJNwC1DIoKUZ2blBBbWTnW1409OMcCAEyFoeolQw+iAIYMCZIMgIHFsQMYBPLBMKtbqxBK4FL7cpHKo1Mh1AAUkHGIPAHX8E3AYK60TqAEosejjqFzt0Gs0OGB9FAfmjgWTRJ4qH8IACgTiwMjmmBwThGAByOBCzTIZhbJYrUjGNgcGDC1gLIj0AD0avi8iImAAdAhMlghQ9xRrkJlUswEP1BsNGJMxExTLR+fj2sgRWLHbQpQJlmi5exOEqVerNXFtXqDUaTcgzdAoJkoB0LB6KPLg0pXKphA9jcByCBMmA6NJgIIQHBFpgzJkzKmhen7NI2opbgRc+ohbrHZ5aNMPITREA)

The question is: can anything be done to make the type-checking on `attributes` within `children` work the same way it does for the top level `attributes`?